# WiX installer: Can not install to network disk

Tags: wix

I have created an installer with Visual Studio 2012 and WiX 3.7. When I try to install this on a terminal server where the local disks are hidden, I need to be able to choose a network path for installation of a file. If I choose a network disk now, I get a message box saying "Installation directory must be on a local hard drive.".

I have tried to add this line to the WiX source:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH" Value="1"/>
```

but without any luck...

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible at least in 3.10.  Add following property to your main product.wxs ...

You must TYPE IN the path you wish to install to fully.

If you try and change it change the Change Folder dialog you will get the error "installation directory must be a local hard drive"

This is a WiX bug and is scheduled to be fixed in WiX 4.0 -  https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4737

Healy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible. You need to map out the network location to make it work.

Check out *[FW: Issue Regarding Install on mapped/shared drives](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/FW-Issue-Regarding-Install-on-mapped-shared-drives-td2101631.html)*.